# Android: How to hide the sliding menu when back button clicked

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-sliding

I am using :

https://github.com/iPaulPro/SlidingMenu

library to implement Facebook like sliding menu, along with ActionBarSherlock library.

The BehindContentView in my case is a ListFragment.

**1. Click on an Image to get the behindView (calling toggle();).**

**2. onListItemClicked takes to an Activity_2 displaying the text of the item clicked.**

**3. in this Activity_2 when i click device back button i get the main Activity_1 but the behindView is open. Usually in Facebook or Google+ the behavior is that, the behindView is hidden when you come back to Activity_1 from any other Activity.**

**4. Moreover on Activity_2 even after having these lines, the home doesn't seem to work(nothing happens when i click the home button).**

```
    ActionBar bar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

How to solve step 3 and 4??

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to hide the sliding menu

on onListItemClicked call hide() OR toggle()

for Home button ActionBar its must work, just handle it  like this

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // you code
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: But i cant use toggle(). in a Fragment which extends SherlockListFragment. toggle() is available only in classes which extent SlidingFragmentActivity.

Comment: so you have the slidingMenu in activity, and the onListItemClicked on fragment. if true. make a listener in your fragment and implement it on the activity

Answer (score 6):

```
SlidingMenu menu;

    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (menu.isMenuShowing()) {
        menu.showContent(true);
        return;
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Boom. on back press in the activity if menu is out, it will just go away

Comment: Did you mean isMenuShowing()?

Answer (score 3):

To hide the sliding menu and to open neede intent you need to give intent you want to open on iten click. Here is small example

```
private SlideMenu slidemenu
// this is from code. no XML declaration necessary, but you won't get state restored after rotation.
slidemenu = new SlideMenu(this, R.menu.slide, this, 333);
// this inflates the menu from XML. open/closed state will be restored after rotation, but you'll have to call init.
slidemenu = (SlideMenu) findViewById(R.id.slideMenu);
slidemenu.init(this, R.menu.IntentName, this, 333);
```

I used the `coboltforge.slidemenu` library.

I think it would be similar in  `iPaulPro`/`SlidingMenu` library.

Comment: I try this, and it put me in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override 
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        getSlidingMenu().toggle(true);
        return false;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Just place this in your Activity.